# need help with solving simple integral using Riemann sums

Tags: limits

Find $\int_{-1}^1 x^3 \, dx$.

$$\int_{-1}^1 x^3 \, dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(c_i) \, \Delta x_i$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(\frac{2i}{n}\right)\frac{2}{n}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{16}{n^4} \cdot \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$
$$= 4$$

Comment: You have $ \displaystyle \left( \frac{2i} n\right) = \frac 8 {n^3} i^3$, so you need to deal with $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 $. That will be a polynomial in $i$ whose leading term is $i^4/4$. $\qquad$

Comment: BTW, notice that you don't need to write $n->\infty$; you can write $n\to\infty$.  I changed it. $\qquad$

Comment: $c_i=-1+\frac{2i}{n}$

Comment: Integral on $(-1,1)$ or on $(0,2)$?

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By some calculations, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1{x^3}dx 
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(c_i)\Delta x_i\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n
   \left(-1+\frac{2i}{n}\right)^3\cdot\frac{1}{n}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n
   \frac{8i^3-12i^2n+6in^2-n^3}{n^3}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left[\frac{8n^2(n+1^2)}{4}-\frac{12n^2(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{6n^3(n+1)}{2}-n^4\right]
   \cdot n^{-4}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(a n^3+b n^2+\cdots\right)
   \cdot n^{-4}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Use defination $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim{x \to \infty } \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(c_i)\Delta x $
where $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $c_i=a+i \Delta x$